# Mysql: Can you use CASE statements in arithmetic?

Tags: mysql, case

Is the following query legal in mysql? In other SQLs? Are there any cases where it's unstable or impossible to use CASE statements in arithmetic? Have you had any experience with doing this, any thoughts about efficiency concerns, etc? (This operation will be working with result sets of thousands of records at a time, eventually tens of thousands, but not much more.)

```
SELECT 
  RAND() * 10 * t.weighting * 
    CASE 
      WHEN t.happiness_level > 9.5 THEN 40
      ELSE 20
    END 
    AS priority
FROM table t
```

Comment: Please define _unstable_.

Comment: Thanks @geomagas. When I tried running a query of this structure, it worked for me. So I don't need to ask "Will this query work?" so much as I want to know "Will it continue to work? Is this a safe approach to this problem?" This is what I mean by unstable: will this approach get me into a hole later on?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it. This is a well-defined, pretty much standard, uniform syntax across many (if not all) SQL dialects. How can such a thing _get you into a hole later on_, and why is there any suspicion that _it won't continue to work_? Do you have a specific concern on your mind?

Comment: @geomagas, it's helpful to hear that this is a "well-defined, pretty much standard" practice. That answers my concerns. There are operations that are possible in Mysql, and (for me at least) reliably produce a reliable & sensible result, but aren't possible in other SQL languages and aren't considered good practice; that's what I mean by unstable. I almost built a major section of my site's functioning around an unreliable technique before coming here and finding out that it would have been impossible to migrate to other SQLs given the approach I was taking. That's what I mean by hole. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your syntax will work in MySQL. You can also use the `IF()` function:

```
SELECT RAND() * 10 * t.weighting * IF(t.happiness_level > 9.5, 40, 20) AS priority
FROM table t
```

I think the `CASE` expressions are portable to most SQL implementations. It's an expression, so it can be used anywhere other expression types are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the opposite , arithmetic inside case statment like that :

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
  WHEN t.happiness_level > 9.5 THEN  RAND() * 10 * t.weighting * 40
  ELSE  RAND() * 10 * t.weighting * 20
END  AS priority
FROM table t
```

Answer (score -1):

**Is the following query legal in mysql?** No, the word `table` is a reserved word in MySQL. You should add backticks. The `case` is legal, though.

**In other SQLs?** Assuming you mean in other DBMS. No, `RAND()` will not work in any DBMS. The `CASE` is standard so it will work in most DBMS but `IF` is not.

**Are there any cases where it's unstable or impossible to use CASE statements in arithmetic?** This question is not clear at all.

**Have you had any experience with doing this, any thoughts about efficiency concerns, etc?** Yes. Yes, apply basic math yourself and decrease the calculation on the server:

```
RAND() * 10 * t.weighting * 
CASE 
  WHEN t.happiness_level > 9.5 THEN 40
  ELSE 20
END
```

Is the same as:

```
RAND() * t.weighting * 
CASE 
  WHEN t.happiness_level > 9.5 THEN 400
  ELSE 200
END
```

Comment: Mosty, I appreciate your sense of humor and I actually learned a couple things from your response. I downvoted because this answer took my dumbed-down example query literally and addressed every part of the (clearly broken) example query except for the question I was asking. I appreciate the SO community for its skill at providing clear and on-topic answers that address the questions being asked, and I thought that this response didn't contribute any insight to the topic I was asking about (namely, the legality and universality of using CASE statements in arithmetic).

Comment: I just can't understand why you considered `The case is legal` as not an answer of `Can you use CASE statements in arithmetic?`. Not to mention the valid query example (which included the case) that would run even faster than the one you provided. The funny thing is that the selected question is just a subset of what I answered and results in a query equally performant but less portable than the one I've provided (as I explained in the answer).